# Festive Email To Close Colleagues

Tags: communication, colleagues, email

First off, I've had a good year at work. I've learnt a lot and progressed in my profession which I attribute to the help of certain people I work with.

I'm your standard introvert type so my idea was to send an email to these individuals just saying thank you and how much I appreciate their help during the year.

Does this sound appropriate? The company doesn't have policies around no personal emails etc. it's a fairly relaxed place. Would you recommend I send out singular emails or on one email to them all with the same message?

Any experience on this would be great to hear.

**Update (If you're interested)**
I've taken the advice and done this face to face - received very well. Thanks all!

Comment: at my workplace, this would be considered odd. Sometimes management will thank everyone for their hard work, but the workers don't typically do this

Comment: @SaggingRufus I had a feeling it might be odd. The list of people does include my own manager and a few other managers around the business but we all get on well - it's not super corporate like some places.

Comment: if you're introvert(like me), the odds that doing something relational you're not used to do will have annoying consequences do skyrocket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with [Snow's answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/124700/16983) that it might come across as a little odd, but I wouldn't say it's inappropriate either. When thanking people like this in any context, individual notes always add a more personal touch. I would normally also suggest a handwritten card, ***but not*** in a workplace setting where everyone will likely see them. The biggest thing you want to avoid is having people know that other people got thanked when they weren't.

Answer (score 5):

I have been in places where people:

- send holiday emails to everyone
- send individual holiday emails
- give holiday cards to everyone
- give holiday cards to specific people

It all depends on the culture of your specific workplace.  At the very least, if you are truly thankful for the help of these colleagues it would be more meaningful to tell them in person how thankful you are.

Comment: This is the best answer. It really boils down to workplace culture. I don't email, I'm more a face to face kind of guy, so I tend to show my gratitude in person. But there's absolutely nothing wrong with an email. Personally, just my opinion, but gratitude is a very important thing to show to people. No one is an island and we often get where we are in life because of the effort and faith other people put in us. Being grateful is always a good thing.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't usual practice for people to do and might well come across as being a strange thing to do.

By all means wish people a happy Christmas in person as and when the need arises, but there's no need to send out an email.